# Rotating Panels & Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have some div's with text and some tabs that correspond. I've been able to get the div's to cycle through and get the tabs to cycle with them. However, I would love for the cycling to pause on hover and I need to get the divs to display when the tab link is clicked.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eFjnU/288/

```
<ul>
    <li id="tab-1" class="active"><a href="#content1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li id="tab-2"><a href="#content2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li id="tab-3"><a href="#content3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li id="tab-4"><a href="#content4">Tab 4</a></li>
    <li id="tab-5"><a href="#content5">Tab 5</a></li>
    <li id="tab-6"><a href="#content6">Tab 6</a></li>
    <li id="tab-7"><a href="#content7">Tab 7</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content-1">Sample text 1</div>
<div id="content-2">Sample text 2</div>
<div id="content-3">Sample text 3</div>
<div id="content-4">Sample text 4</div>
<div id="content-5">Sample text 5</div>
<div id="content-6">Sample text 6</div>
<div id="content-7">Sample text 7</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
i = 0;
tabs = $('li[id^="tab-"]');

(function cycle() { 

divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
          .delay(4000)
          .fadeOut(400, cycle);

tabs.eq(i).addClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active");    

i = ++i % divs.length;

})();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this:

```
var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
i = 0;
tabs = $('li[id^="tab-"]');

var over=false;
var time;
tabs.mouseenter(function(){
    over=true;
}).mouseleave(function(){
    over=false;
    window.clearTimeout(time);
    cycle();
}).click(function(){
    over=true;
    var e=$(this);
    i=e.index();
    divs.eq($(".active").index()).fadeOut(400,function(){
        var ele=divs.eq(i);    
        tabs.removeClass("active").eq(i).addClass("active");
        ele.fadeIn(400);
    });
});

function cycle() { 
    var ele=divs.eq(i);    
    tabs.eq(i).addClass("active").siblings(".active").removeClass("active");
    ele.fadeIn(400,function(){
        time=window.setTimeout(function(){
            if(!over){
                ele.fadeOut(400,function(){ 
                    i = ++i % divs.length;
                    cycle();
                });
            }
        },4000);
    });
}
cycle();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mGgaA/1/

Comment: Ok...I am stuck again.
I am trying to implement this here (in a Wordpress site), but as you can see the panels aren't hiding and aren't rotating.

http://www.olympiaauto.net/wp/?page_id=95

Comment: you need document.ready [http://jsfiddle.net/mGgaA/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/mGgaA/2/)